# How to create column with the numbers 0 or 1 when substraction two columns in the same dataframe is less than zero?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In a simple example, I have a dataframe that looks like this (I am going to put in a dict structure, but it is really a dataframe):

```
data = {'value': [1,2,3,4,5,1,3,4,6],
        'limit': [4,4,4,4,3,3,3,1,1],
        }
data = pd.Dataframe(data)
```

I need add an extra column to dataframe that look like this:

```
data = {'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 6],
        'limit': [4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1],
        'criteria': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
        }

    ''' The criteria is determined as follows (example):
    Looking at the row zero: 
value is 1. 
limit is 4. 
diff is -3. 
Given that -3 < 0 (less then 0). 
Criteria is 0.
    
    Looking at the row 4: 
value is 5. 
limit is 3. 
diff is 2 (higher than 0). 
Criteria is 1.'''


data['criteria'] = data[((data['value'] - df1['limit']) > 0) == 1]
```

Nevertheless, it does not work because I am not really assigning any values to the criteria column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, which uses [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data['criteria'] = np.where((data['value'] - data['limit']) > 0, 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
   value  limit  criteria
0      1      4         0
1      2      4         0
2      3      4         0
3      4      4         0
4      5      3         1
5      1      3         0
6      3      3         0
7      4      1         1
8      6      1         1
```

Comment: Is it possible just to add the times the criteria is 1 without creating any additional column? For example in this case the count will be 3.

Comment: @ananvodo: you mean replacing 1 by the count of 1 in the column `criteria`?

Comment: no. Just having a variable as integer. In this case: count= {code}. If I print count it would be 3. No Criteria column will be added.

Comment: You can use the following for that: `count = np.sum(np.where((data['value'] - data['limit']) > 0, 1, 0))`, @ananvodo.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result by simply computing the test as a boolean and converting to `int`:

```py
data['criteria'] = ((data['value'] - data['limit']) > 0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   value  limit  criteria
0      1      4         0
1      2      4         0
2      3      4         0
3      4      4         0
4      5      3         1
5      1      3         0
6      3      3         0
7      4      1         1
8      6      1         1
```

If you just want to know how many times the test was true, simply `sum` the test results:

```py
count = sum((data['value'] - data['limit']) > 0)
```

Output:

```
3
```